# Is there any non-heap memory limit in java 8?

Tags: memory, java-8, rcp, jvm-crash

I'm encountring a critical problem. working on a Java RCP app (desktop) which is frequently crashing on my machine (not on the machine of my collegue).

I set the xmx and the xms as the config of my collegue app and i run a diagnostic on memory but the app still crashes.

according to the charts of memory diagnostics, at the moment of the crash, the non heap memory is increasing (because of the increase of loaded classes). the RAM of the  computer of my collegue is about 3 times superior to the RAM on my machine . After setting the heap memoy (xmx & xms) like on the other machine, i'm suspecting a heap memory problem(i'm using the last version of java 8).

There is any way to know the limit of the heap memory?

Does  the value of the ram affect the non-heap memory?

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us exactly what messages you are getting when it crashes.

Comment: There is no messages at the moment of the crash i looked into the logs + the ".metadata" logs in my workspace. After some investigation i suspect the Metaspace (non-heap). I'd like to know if there is any limitation to the Metaspace used by the java app. As i explained above: the app never crashes on an another machine with bigger RAM.

Comment: Crash logs may be written in the 'configuration' directory in the RCP install location. Java metaspace is unlimited unless you specify -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize

Comment: It is extremely unusual not to get some sort of log on a crash. Try starting the app from the command line and specify the -consoleLog and -debug options to get messages in the command window.